# Laravel blade: Select option enlazado a input text (valor del input depende del option seleccionado)

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

como dice el título estoy tratando de llenar el valor de un input text dependiendo a la selección del select:

Lo que trato de hacer es seleccionar una liga en el select, la cual esta insertada en la tabla "ligas", y que de manera automática se llene el input text "territorio_id"

La ruta:

```html
Route::get('/buscarTerritorio','DistritalController@buscarTerritorio');
```

El controller:

```html
use App\Models\Liga;
use App\Models\Distrital;
use App\Http\Requests\DistritalRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\LigaRequest;

    public function buscarTerritorio(LigaRequest $request)
    {
        $p=Liga::select('territorio_id')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
        return response()->json($p);
    }
```

El JS:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','.liga_id',function () {
            var prod_id=$(this).val();
            var a=$(this).parent().parent();
            a.css('background-color','blue');
            console.log(prod_id);
            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('buscarTerritorio')!!}',
                data:{'id':prod_id},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("territorio_id");
                    console.log(data.territorio_id);
                    a.find('.territorio_id').val(data.territorio_id);
                },
                error:function(){
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

El blade:

```html
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('liga_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <x-label for="liga_id" value="{{ __('League') }}" />
        <select id="liga_id" class="liga_id block mt-1 w-full" name="liga_id" required>
            <option value="" >Selecciona liga</option>
            @foreach ($ligas as $liga)
                <option value="{{ $liga['id'] }}" @if($liga['id']==$distrital->liga_id) selected @endif>{{ $liga['liga'] }} ({{ $liga['territorio_id'] }})</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <x-input type="text" class="territorio_id" id="territorio_id" name="territorio_id" value="{{ $liga['territorio_id'] }}" />
```

Creo que el error esta en el JS o en el blade no se si me pueden ayudar